# multicolor grapf in networkx

Tags: python-3.x, networkx

I have no way how to not make each dictionary multi-colored. I try to do this way, but it turns out all in one color. What am I missing?

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

uber_dict={'y': {('VD3', 'VD5'): 0, ('VD3', 'VD8'): 0}, 'blue': {('R1', 'R3'): 1, ('R1', 'R2'): 1, ('R1', 'R4'): 1}, 'green': {('VD1', 'VD2'): 0, ('VD1', 'VD7'): 0, ('VD1', 'VD6'): 0}, 'red': {('DD2', 'DD3'): 4, ('DD2', 'VD4'): 1, ('DD2', 'DD1'): 5}}

g = nx.Graph()
for cvet, slovar in uber_dict.items():
    for e, p in slovar.items():
        g.add_edge(*e, weight=p)

pos = nx.circular_layout(g)
edge_labels = {(u, v): d['weight'] for u, v, d in g.edges(data=True)}
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(g, pos, node_size=600, node_color=cvet)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(g, pos)
nx.draw_networkx_labels(g, pos)
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(g, pos, edge_labels=edge_labels, font_color='r')

plt.title("Входная схема")
plt.axis('off')
# plt.show()
plt.savefig('output.png')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of `cvet` in this line:

```
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(g, pos, node_size=600, node_color=cvet)
```

is whatever it was the last time through the for loop.  So you're telling it to draw the graph with all nodes having whatever color that happened to be.

to fix the problem you can create a list of nodes and pass that in to the drawing command as `nodelist`, and also a list of colors (rather than the single value `cvet`) such that node `nodelist[i]` should have color `colorlist[i]`.